Wordpress: How to dynamically change sender email and from name within PHP function
I am using the following function to send emails on a WordPress website:
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'my_phpmailer_smtp' );
function my_phpmailer_smtp( $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->From = 'Info';
    $phpmailer->FromName = 'info@domain.com';
}

We are currently building some custom functionality, sending transactional emails from the website. The sender from name/email depends on a few different factors and should dynamically updated.
Now, after setting the default from email and from name like above, how can I dynamically updated these within another PHP function? I have tried calling this phpmailer_init again within our own function, but then the from email and name are just empty.
Here's what I tried but not working (simplified):
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'my_phpmailer_smtp' );
function my_phpmailer_smtp( $phpmailer ) {
    // default settings
    $phpmailer->From = 'Info';
    $phpmailer->FromName = 'info@domain.com';
}

function my_send_email($to,$subject,$body,$from_email='',$from_name='') {

    if($from_email && $from_name) {
        // Overwriting default settings - not working - results in empty sender details when receiving email
        add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'custom_phpmailer_smtp' );
        function custom_phpmailer_smtp( $phpmailer ) {
            $phpmailer->From = $from_email;
            $phpmailer->FromName = $from_name;
        }
    } else {
        $from_name = 'Info';
        $from_email = 'info@domain.com';
    }

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'From: '.$from_name.' <'.$from_email.'>';
    $headers[] = 'Reply-To: '.$from_name.' <'.$from_email.'>';
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );

}

Any help would be appreciated.

You should pass a variable that will contain an email. How to pass the correct email depends on your factors. Could you please provide an example of such factors?

I have added a simplified example of what I tried. The email is sending, but the sender from name and email are black.

The point when the phpmailer_init callbacks get executed, probably has already passed, when you try to add another callback function there. You could try if explicitly calling do_action afterwards helps.

I'm not really sure what you mean, but changing the add_action by do_action doesn't do anything..

Have you tried using the dedicated wp_mail_from and wp_mail_from_name hooks?

Thanks for the suggestion, but I was able to get it working. It seemed the values for $from_email and $from_name were just not passing along correctly to the nested function custom_phpmailer_smtp. I solved it by using the $GLOBALS variable and first removing the default phpmailer_init function, see my answer below.

Although, looking through the code, if a FROM header is present it will be used unless changed by something else. So maybe only use the hooks to see if the default wordpress@ is used, and change it only then.

I was able to get it working. It seemed the values for $from_email and $from_name were just not passing along correctly to the nested function custom_phpmailer_smtp. I solved it by using the $GLOBALS variable and first removing the default phpmailer_init function I set earlier:
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'my_phpmailer_smtp' );
function my_phpmailer_smtp( $phpmailer ) {
    // default settings
    $phpmailer->From = 'Info';
    $phpmailer->FromName = 'info@domain.com';
}

function my_send_email($to,$subject,$body,$from_email='',$from_name='') {

    if($from_email && $from_name) {

        $GLOBALS['from_email'] = $from_email;
        $GLOBALS['from_name'] = $from_name;

        // Overwriting default settings
        remove_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'my_phpmailer_smtp' );
        add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'custom_phpmailer_smtp' );
        function custom_phpmailer_smtp( $phpmailer ) {
            $phpmailer->From = $GLOBALS['from_email'];
            $phpmailer->FromName = $GLOBALS['from_name'];
        }
    } else {
        $from_name = 'Info';
        $from_email = 'info@domain.com';
    }

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'From: '.$from_name.' <'.$from_email.'>';
    $headers[] = 'Reply-To: '.$from_name.' <'.$from_email.'>';
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );

}


Although not necessarily wrong, stashing things in global scope is usually frowned upon. Instead, you can use closures or anonymous functions to do this, see https://3v4l.org/NFAFN#v8.3.8

That's an interesting solution, one I didn't know yet. Thank you for this, will certainly check it out in detail and see if I can adapt my own code to make it more efficient. Thanks!
